# Javascript: How to check/compare if a String contains some tag?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to use pure JS to check if some String, the `textareas .innerHTML` = `newContent` below, contains some tag (`h1`in my case) at the beginning (=as first child). What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks!

```
function submitNewSectionContent(e) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++)
        let newHeading = document.getElementById('edit-title').value; 
        /* edit-title is text-input*/
        let newContent = document.getElementById('edit-sectionText').innerHTML; 
        /* edit-sectionText is textarea */
        if (newContent.indexOf('<h1>') > -1 && newContent.indexOf('<h1>') < 10) {  /* <h1> is at beginning so replace with newHeading */
            let toberemoved = newContent.match('<h1>.*<\/h1>');
            newContent = newContent.replace(toberemoved[0], '').trim();
            sections[i].innerHTML = '<h1>'+newHeading+'</h1>' + sections[i].innerHTML;
        } else { /* newContent has no h1 as first child, so add h1 from newHeading */
            sections[i].innerHTML = '<h1>'+newHeading+'</h1>' + newContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to search the string, rather than see if the element has a `h1` child?

Comment: Also, in what way is your current solution not working? What does 'beginning' mean for you?

Comment: @IMP1: `the element` you are referring to, is a textarea for live-HTML editing. And I'd like to see if the user input (.innerHTML) contains a `h1`element as first element. There is no DOM to traverse. So I don't know how to do this best.

Comment: Why not `indexOf('<h1>') === 0` for the beginning? Also you might consider finding the DOM element via [`Node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) and simply replacing its `innerHTML`

Comment: You should not be using regex or any other type of string comparisons on `.innerHTML` because `.innerHTML` might contain `<!--<h1>Ignore me</h1>-->`.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson: Do you have a better solution besides regexes?

Comment: What is the best way, convert it to a DOM fragment and do your checks. Reg Exp on HTML is a bad idea. And text area has a value, not innerHTML.

Comment: @epascarello. Thanks. Thats the most useful answer/comment so far. I assume you mean by using `.innerHTML` on some temporary parent element?

Comment: A `textarea` has both an `innerHTML` and a `value` property. If the textarea contains `<h1>` and you inspect `innerHTML`, you will see `&lt;h1&gt;` but `value` will contain `<h1>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with Regular expressions is they do not really work well with HTML. So Your best bet is to convert it to a DOM fragment and do the manipulations and convert it back. Only issue with this method really is you can lose formatting. There are libraries out there that can pretty print HTML.

```js
function updateHeadline(txt) {
  const ta = document.querySelector("textarea");
  const data = ta.value; // read value, not innerHTML
  const temp = document.createElement('div'); // temp div to hold html
  temp.innerHTML = data; // set the html to the temp element
  let firstChild = temp.firstElementChild // look at the dom
  if (!firstChild || firstChild.tagName!=="H1") { // see if we have an h1
    firstChild = document.createElement("h1") // if not create one
    temp.prepend(firstChild) // add it to the front
  }
  firstChild.innerHTML = txt // set the new text of the h1
  ta.value = temp.innerHTML // put the content back into the textarea
}

const btn = document.querySelector("button");
btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  updateHeadline(document.querySelector("#text").value)  
})
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea>
&lt;p&gt;Some other text&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Some more text&lt;/p&gt;
</textarea>

<input value="foo" id="text"/>
<button>Set</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex like so, (updated based on comment)

```
if( /^\s*&lt;h1&gt;/gi.test(stringToTest) ) {
 //logic here
}
```

It checks if the stringToTest begins with `^`  tag

See here : https://regex101.com/r/vSo4sL/1

Comment: I'd add the possibility of whitespace between the start of the string and the opening `h1` tag. Something like `/^\s*<h1>/`

Comment: What if `stringToTest` is `<!--<h1>Ignore me</h1>-->`?

Comment: Debugger says that my `newContent` String, starts like: `"\n\t\t&lt;h1&gt;Topic 2&lt;/h1&gt;\n\t\t&lt;img src=\"pic2.jpg\"&gt; Lorem ipsum `. So this doesn't match (I tested). How would you handle the `<>`?

Comment: Ok, surely this works now. But my mistake was to use `.innerHTML` instead of `.value` on the textarea. Like @epascarello commented. You still get +1 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is: [**`Node.firstElementChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) which will avoid giving child node as `#text` for white-spaces and [**`Node.nodeName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName)

```
let firstChild = document.getElementById('edit-sectionText').firstElementChild;
if(firstChild.nodeName === "H1"){
firstChild.innerHTML = "Replacement Value"
}
```

**Note & Update:** The earlier api that I had suggested [**`Node.firstChild`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) will not prevent white-spaces which gives `#text` node and comments as `#comment` node.

**2nd Way:** [**`Node.children`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) and picking the first child out of it should have a similar result to `Node.firstElementChild`.

```
let elem = document.getElementById('edit-sectionText');
if(elem){
let firstChild = elem.children[0];
}
```

**Update based on comments:** Using [Dom Parser Interface](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#the-domparser-interface)

The interface allows to parse XML or HTML source from a string based on the mime type provided for its method *`parseFromString(string, mimeType)`*

It will give the top level `#document` node with parsed HTML from the string where if exists `<h1>` or `<H1>` at the beginning would be the first child of `body` and subsequently can be tested via `tagName` property.

***Note:*** Takes care of preceding HTML comments and spaces at the beginning but a caveat is doesn't check fully closed tags ex: `var s = \t  <h1>I am a heading <h1>` here the `<h1>` was never closed and in the result will two fully formed headings at the body with content : `I am a heading` and ""

```
let textAreaString = document.getElementById("edit-sectionText").value;
const domParser = new DOMParser();

const parsedDoc = domParser.parseFromString(textAreaString, "text/html");

if (parsedDoc.body.firstElementChild.tagName === "H1") {
  //yes it starts with <h1> or <H1>
}
```

Comment: I just tested it. At first it was returning `#text` and then I saw your update. But somehow also `.firstElementChild`returns `null`. So `firstChild`is null for some reason. I think this is because a textarea can't be travered(i.e. has only `#text` as child).

Comment: @avermaet Yes! `textArea` is self contained element tag and does not have children to traverse. My question: Why would the `textArea` that you have would contain HTML tags. I believe you case is when u would like to check if textArea content contains (which is String) HTML tag as part of it ..Isn't it?

Comment: Exactly, I want to check if .innerHTML (=a string) of the textarea contains a <h1> element at beginning. So far all the `firstChild`,`firstEleemntChild`and `children[0]`returned null, or `#text` in case of `firstChild` . The textarea to which `document.getElementById('edit-sectionText');` referrs to does not have children.  (children length is 0 in debugger.) So all the traversal and indexing doesn't work.

Comment: @avermaet Don't know why the downvote. Pretty late to the answer train, I guess.. but have updated the answer with another way based on comments.

Comment: I don't know either, it wasn't me. But +1 for your input about the DOMParser. I didn't verify its correctness anymore, since I already got my solution from the accepted answer, but maybe it will be of help for someone else searching for similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

## convert to dom, and parse dom

this portion of code makes it possible to treat a chain to retrieve titles placed in the H1 tag and (on the fly) treat the string of characters.

It's easily expandable for future processing :  or  tag processing or other ...!

## commented code

```
<html>


<script>

 var s="<H1>Hey Title</H1>\n Hello,\n other title <H1>Green!</H1>\n Ipsum dolore sit...";
 console.log(s);
 console.log("-------------------------");

 var partialDoc = document.createElement( 'html' );
 partialDoc.innerHTML = s;

 var parsed='';
 var titles=[]; 

 treatment(partialDoc);

 console.log("\n-------------------------\n");
 console.log("parsed",parsed);

 console.log("\n-------------------------\n");
 console.log("s var contains "+titles.length+ " H1 tag");
 console.log("titles  "+titles);


 function treatment(root) {


    var child = root.firstChild;

    while (child) {

      // child.nodeName = H1 | H2 | P etc...
      // child.nodeType = 1

      // catch H1
      if (child.nodeName=='H1') {
        // append your title,
        parsed+=" [H1 FOUND content= {"+child.innerText+"} H1])";
        // or 
        // parsed+="<H1>"+child.innerText+"<H1>";

        // add your own process here
        // add this title in array
        // or what you want...      
        titles.push(child.innerText);

        // next part of document
        child = child.nextSibling;
        continue;
      }

      // capture other text than H1
      if (child.nodeType==3) { // Node Type Text
        parsed+=child.nodeValue;
      }

      if (child.nodeType==1) { // Node Type ELEMENT, : sub nodes...
        treatment(child);
      }

      // continue the rest of doc
      child = child.nextSibling;

    }

 }

</script>

</html>
```

[image: Console output]